# Get the .tf file from azure remote backend in terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I am trying the terraform operations using azure as remote backend. So far, I have been able to store the state remotely in azure. I am now unable to retrieve the state from remote, as I do not store the .tf files or .tfstate files locally. How to fetch the same from remote? This is the code I have:

```
terraform init -backend-config=config.backend.tfbackend
terraform state pull # fails due to no configuration file existing locally
```

This is my config.backend.tfbackend

```
 backend "azurerm" {
   resource_group_name      = "rg098"
   storage_account_name     = "tstate6565"
   container_name           = "tstate"
   key                      = "test5176"
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to pull the state locally?

Comment: @MarkoE This is to get the state and make changes to the infrastructure. Basically I want to get the .tf or .tfstate file and make changes to the existing resources.

Comment: Why not use the `terraform state` comman?

Comment: And you cannot change the terraform code and apply changes?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you please elaborate on the terraform state command? How to use it without a local config file?

Comment: @MarkoE My terraform code resides in the config file, which is present on Azure cloud, not locally.